# Why does bash "=~" operator ignore the last part of the pattern specified?

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to do compare a string in bash to a regex pattern and have found something odd. For starters I am using GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu). This is within WSL.

For example here is sample program demonstrating the problem:

```
#!/bin/env bash

name="John"

if [[ "${name}" =~ "John"* ]]; then
    echo "found"
else
    echo "not found"
fi

exit
```

As expected this will echo `found` since the name "John" matches the regex pattern described. Now what I find odd is if I drop the n in John, it still echos `found`. Imo "Joh" does match the pattern of "John"*.

If you drop the "hn" and just set $name to "Jo" then it echos `not found`. It seems to only affect the last character in the Regex pattern (aside from the wildcard).

I am converting an old csh script to bash and this behavior is not happening in csh. What is causing bash to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing up syntax for shell patterns and regular expressions. Your regular expression, after stripping the quoting, is `John*`: `Joh` followed by any number of `n`, including 0. Matches `Joh`, `John`, `Johnn`, `Johnnn`, ...

It's not anchored, so it also matches any string containing one of the matches above.

Since it's not anchored, depending on what you want, you could do any of these:

- Any string containing `John` should match:

  - Regex: `[[ $name =~ John ]]`
  - Shell pattern: `[[ $name == *John* ]]`
- Any string that begins with `John` should match:

  - Regex: `[[ $name =~ ^John ]]`
  - Shell pattern: `[[ $name == John* ]]`

Notice that shell patterns, unlike the regular expressions, must match the entire string.

A note on quoting: within `[[ ... ]]`, the left-hand side doesn't have to be quoted; on the right-hand side, quoted parts are interpreted literally. For regular expressions, it's a good practice to define it in a separate variable:

```bash
re='^John'
if [[ $name =~ $re ]]; then
```

This avoids a few edge cases with special characters in the regex.

Comment: ah this makes sense. I obviously modified what I am working on for a simple example but the problem I am trying to work on involves looking for a string that must start with some certain characters and then can have anything after it. The solution using ^ was exactly what I was after. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The `=~` operator compares using regular expression syntax, not glob syntax. The `*` isn't a shell wildcard, it means, "the previous character, 0 or more times".

The string `Joh` matches the regular expression `John*` because it contains `Joh` followed by zero `n` characters.

Comment: Missed it by *this* much... :)

Comment: Regarding my edit, I'd be careful to call it a regular expression, since "pattern matching" is the name of the operation that matches against globs, so it helps to reserve the word "pattern" for something that uses glob syntax.